# Refresh of plot inside of class

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm testing the interactive brokers api, where I'm trying to plot some date in real time.

Everytime we get new data, the function `tickPrice` inside of the class TestApp is executed. Inside of this class, I can plot and update the data.

```
class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient, Plotter):

    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def tickPrice(self, some_parameters):

        price = we_have_the_new_price

        # to plot the first time 
        if(self.boot_plot == False):
            self.boot_plot = True
            self.plotthing()

        else:
            print('Animate')
            self.updating()
```

The plotting class is defined in the following way:

```
class Plotter(object):

    fig = None
    sp = None

    def plotthing(self):
        print('plotting for the first time.')
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.sp = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.sp.plot(self.price, 'o-')
        self.data = np.random.rand(10)
        plt.show(block = False)

    def updating(self):
        print('updating')
        self.sp.cla();
        self.sp.plot(price, 'o-')
        plt.show(block = False)
```

However, when I run this code, nothing happens, i.e., I cannot see any image. Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is the issue without seeing the rest of your code (eg the imports, the actual statement that you're calling, etc), but you have a typo in your def of `updating`:

```
    def updating(self):
        print('updating')
        self.sp.cla();
        self.sp.plot(price, 'o-')
        plt.show(block = False)
```

The `plot` line should be `self.sp.plot(self.price, 'o-')`, right?

The other obvious answer is that there's something wrong with your env/setup of your matplotlib backend. If you just do a simple plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot((0,1), (0,1))
plt.show()
```

does that show up correctly? If not, you have a config problem.